# python improving time of find line and remove line in 3Gb file

Tags: python, dictionary, large-files

first post,
be as critical as you want...

My problem:
I have a really large file of 140 million lines (file 1) and a slightly smaller file of 3 million lines (file 2). I want to remove those lines in file 1 that have matches to file 2. Intuitively this seemed like a simple find and remove problem that shouldn't take that long..relatively. As my code stands its taking ~4 days to run on a 24Gb processor. I'd like to perform this on several files and so I would like an improvement on time.
Any help and comments would be much appreciated.

**Sample file1:**

```
reftig_0 43 0 1.0
reftig_0 44 1 1.0
reftig_0 45 0 1.0
reftig_0 46 1 1.0
reftig_0 47 0 5.0
```

**Sample file 2:**

```
reftig_0 43
reftig_0 44
reftig_0 45
```

**Code:**

```
data = open('file_1', 'r')
data_2 = open('file_2', 'r')
new_file = open('new_file_1', 'w')

d2= {}
for line in data_2:
    line= line.rstrip()
    fields = line.split(' ')
    key = (fields[0], fields[1])
    d2[key]=1

#print d2.keys()
#print d2['reftig_1']
tocheck=d2.keys()
tocheck.sort()
#print tocheck

for sline in data:
    sline = sline.rstrip()
    fields = sline.split(' ')
    nkey = (fields[0],fields[1])
    #print nkey
    if nkey in tocheck:
        pass
    else:
        new_file.write(sline + '\n')
        #print sline
```

Comment: You have a 24Gb processor? Where do I get one? :P

Comment: if the data in the file is ordered(as it seems): why dont you just read both files side by side and only write all the lines that dont match the next line in file2?

Comment: i meant RAM sorry. and the file is not actually ordered and so falls out of sync eventually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing short strings to `new_file` once per line is slow. Reduce the number of writes by appending content to a list, and writing to `new_file` only when the list is, say, 1000 lines long.

```
N = 1000
with open('/tmp/out', 'w') as f:
    result = []
    for x in range(10**7):
        result.append('Hi\n')
        if len(result) >= N:
            f.write(''.join(result))
            result = []
```

Here is the result of running `time test.py` for various values of `N`:

```
|      N | time (sec) |
|      1 |      5.879 |
|     10 |      2.781 |
|    100 |      2.417 |
|   1000 |      2.325 |
|  10000 |      2.299 |
| 100000 |      2.309 |
```

Comment: Thanks everyone I am now down to an hour!

Answer (score 4):

This may be better approached using `grep`:

```
grep -Fvf file2 file1
```

Comment: this takes out way more than expected lines...I am trying without the -F

Answer (score 4):

Your script is slow because the line `if nkey in tocheck` is checking `nkey` against a *`list`*. This is very, very slow because it is a linear search (even though `tocheck` is sorted).

Use a `set` instead:

```
def getkey(line):
    line = line.rstrip()
    fields = line.split(' ')
    return (fields[0], fields[1])

tocheck = {getkey(line) for line in data_2}

for line in data:
    if getkey(line) not in tocheck:
        new_file.write(line)
```

Combine that with unutbu's write-batching, and your script should run pretty quick.